# Keywords recommendation not working. Amazon advertising api v3

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to implement the https://advertising-api.amazon.com/sp/targets/keywords/recommendation API but for some reason I always get `{"message":"Unauthorized"}` even tough everything else works with the credentials.

Is this because this API is on v3 and still in beta?

Comment: Well, possible but unlikely.
Check your region and the api endpoint for that region. BETA maybe don't support your region.

Comment: @tector yeah, probably, ty for your reply. Will try some time later when it's fully launched